# synchronize local and remote web site

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, database-design, synchronization

I'm trying to develop a web site, which has got two parts: a local part and remote part on the internet.

Users update local web site daily and remote web site should synchronize itself by local part (or it can be done by users manually).

The web site contains one `mysql` database with 4 or 5 tables and some images as files.

Now I'm searching for the best way to understand the system that this picture or row is new, so you should insert it or it has been modified, so update it.

I'm thinking about `timestamp` and random `md5` as fields in every database and another database to keep names of files. So, check them and if one thing (timestamp or random md5) changed, update those rows.

Is this a good way, or is there an easier way to do this? I want to develop this web site with Yii or CodeIgniter and Mysql database.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the local/remote architecture you are looking to build, but if you are looking to allow users to make updates to a database via the application and want a remote database synche to those updates, you might consider using MySQL replication.

Comment: web site exist in local network of researching Lab in university.so researchers update site information in the whole of the day and sync remote website with their local server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files, I would use [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html).

```
rsync -avz /www/development USERNAME@REMOTE_HOST:/www/production/
```

For MySQL, I would create a cron script that updates the SQL table.

```
mysqldump -al --password=LOCAL_PASS --add-drop-table DB_NAME TABLE_NAME | mysql -h REMOTE_HOST --password=REMOTE_PASS DB_NAME;
```

The idea of a timestamp would work if you want to grab individual records at a time. Then you should keep a last_sync record, and select * from table where date > last_sync.

Quite a few ways to skin this cat.

Comment: which way is more effective ? faster and using less resource ?

Comment: Updating only modified data would require less bandwidth, and should be significantly faster depending on database size.

Answer (score 4):

1. Setup MySQL replication.
2. If your remote server can't connect to your local server, turn on the general log and replay it periodically on the remote server.
3. If you can't do either of those, create a 'last_modified' column of type TIMESTAMP with "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". You do not need to ever update this column directly, any changes to the row will automatically update it. With this you can do a select/dump of rows changed and create a script to update those rows on your remote host.